std::ranges::any_of Order implementation details
I am looking at cppreference but I don't see any information on the order of the executed loop.
My question: when calling std::ranges::any_of on data.begin(), data.end() am I sure it goes from begin() to end() in order and it stop once true?

The guarantee is "...: At most last - first applications of the predicate and any projection...." [alg.any.of] ie the order is not specified and it does not have to stop on the 1st true although I would expect every implementation to do this.


am I sure it goes from begin() to end() in order and it stop once true?

No, there is no such guarantee.
According to the stated complexity for std::ranges::any_of:

At most last - first applications of the predicate and the projection.

The implementation is free to iterate in a different order than the one you mentioned (e.g. in reverse order). It is also not obligated to stop at the first elements for which the predicate is true. The only guarantee is that it will use the predicate/projection on each element at most 1 time.
Having said that, what you mentioned is a very reasonable expectation from any "normal" implementation, and I assume all of them will follow it (although as I said it is not mandated).

Strictly speaking, the standard does not specify.
However, per the C++ standard, [alg.any.of] any_of is defined as:
template<class InputIterator, class Predicate>
constexpr bool any_of(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Predicate pred);

[algorithms.requirements]/4.1 says:

If an algorithm’s template parameter is named InputIterator, InputIterator1, or InputIterator2, the template argument shall meet the Cpp17InputIterator requirements

And [tab:inputiterator] (from [input.iterators]) only has the requirements of a != b, *a, a->m, ++r, (void)r++, and *r++
Thus, since the only requirement on the iterators (in terms of traversal) is ++r or r++, it's logical to assume that the function will go from first to last in order.

Is there text that prohibits the function from detecting and taking advantage of other operations supported by the iterator (like --)?

@RaymondChen, not that I can tell. Technically, even without that, it could search in reverse order by taking advantage of std::distance and std::advance, though that'd be a tad silly. Hence the logical to assume part of my answer :)
